# Boost versions on c++ builder

Tags: c++, boost, c++builder, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I tried using boost 1.61 with C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin by replacing the default boost version (1.55) with boost 1.61 but that didn't work, how can i use newer boost versions on c++ builder

Comment: What was the error when using 1.61?

Comment: On which platform are you trying to upgrade to version 1.61 ?

Comment: @jrbedard nothing works, when i compile i get about 103 errors and 665 warnings linking to the boost headers i included

Comment: @mystic_coder on windows 64-bit

Comment: What version of C++ Builder are you using?

Comment: @TinyT C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin

Comment: I remember Seattle having serious issues with 64b boost in general. They seem to have fixed [part of them](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/44675). Do you see rather missing entry points, wrong definitions or something entirely different? It's well possible the Embarcadero people set custom defines (again) to make things work.

Comment: @TinyT `unknown type name` is the error i get the most

Comment: That is usually symptomatic of missing `#define` macros, especially inside C++ Builder. The typical workaround is to search the missing type declarations inside your boost headers, find out which defines are missing (and therefore prevent the declarations from being included), and add them to your project properties as additional defines (should be somewhere inside the main C++ tabs, I don't use C++ Builder any more and can't look them up myself, I'm afraid). I think there is some compiler version define you need to fake, but sadly, I don't have my notes on that any more.

Comment: Upvote the "[Allow Boost Upgrades](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13487?filter=13000)" feature request. But expect nothing to happen, this is Embarcadero after all...